# Insert array as new rows in postgresql without a loop

Tags: arrays, postgresql

I have a function that takes 3 values:

```
partitionId varchar(48)='tenant';
jobId varchar(40)='job1';
taskIds varchar[] := '{job1.1, job1.5, job1.3}';
```

I would like to have those inserted in a table as:

```
tenant  job1    job1.1  2020-10-09 11:38:03
tenant  job1    job1.5  2020-10-09 11:38:03
tenant  job1    job1.3  2020-10-09 11:38:03
```

I know that I could use a loop on the array then insert one by one, but I believe it's not the most efficient so, I am trying to insert in one go.
Not sure if I should use an intermediary table for that or if there's a more direct solution.

I tried:

```
DO
$do$
DECLARE
  
    partitionId varchar(48)='tenant';
    jobId varchar(40)='job1';
    taskIds varchar[] := '{job1.1, job1.5, job1.3}';
begin
    
    insert into completed_subtask_report values (partitionId, jobId, taskIds, current_timestamp );
    
END
$do$
```

But that would insert the array as:

```
tenant  job1    {job1.1,job1.5,job1.3}  2020-10-09 12:44:09
```

Anyone knows how to do that?

Comment: If you have received a satisfactory answer please accept it. Please do not leave answered questions as unanswered.

Comment: sorry, my bad, just did.Thx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use unnest:

```
insert into completed_subtask_report ( ... column names go here ...)
select 'tenant', 'job1', x.task, current_timestamp
from unnest('{job1.1, job1.5, job1.3}') as x(task)
```